# An OCR model that can be easily improved on the user side

Tags: machine-learning, modeling, svm, libsvm, optical-character-recognition

I am building OCR software, for this purpose I trained a model on many types of fonts, the model is `SVM` but it is not principled.

Now I want the users of the software to be able to improve the model they received from me, when the users come across a font that the model does not recognize accurately, they will want to improve the model, how can they do this?

For this purpose, do I need to bring them the model together with all the training data, and all the pictures of the letters, and will they have to do the whole long training from the beginning for every letter that the users want to add to the model?

Or is there a way to bring users a ready-made model and on the other hand give users the option to improve the model easily?

Is there a type of model that you can add letters to without rebuilding it?

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with an interesting challenge. The short answer is that, in general, SVMs are not easily updated with new training data without retraining, but there are alternative approaches you can consider.

Incremental learning: Some machine learning models support incremental learning, which allows you to update the model with new data without needing to retrain on the entire dataset. Models such as Naive Bayes, k-Nearest Neighbors (k-NN), and certain neural networks support incremental learning. Note, however, that these models may not be as effective as SVMs for OCR.

Online SVM: There are variations of SVM, known as Online SVMs, that can be updated incrementally. This could be an option if you wish to stick to SVMs.

Transfer Learning: For your use-case, transfer learning could be a very effective approach. Deep learning models, specifically Convolutional Neural Networks (CNNs), have achieved state-of-the-art results in OCR tasks. You can provide a pre-trained CNN model to your users, which can then be fine-tuned on specific fonts that users come across. This fine-tuning process typically requires much less data and computational resources than training a model from scratch.

Active Learning: This is a semi-supervised learning approach where the model identifies instances in the dataset for which it is least confident and requests their labels from the user. This approach can be very efficient when labeling data is expensive or time-consuming.

In your situation, I would recommend exploring transfer learning with a deep learning model. This would allow users to improve the model with new fonts without needing to retrain from scratch. It's also worth noting that deep learning models tend to perform better than SVMs for image-based tasks like OCR.

Remember, any model improvement approach will require careful design of the user interface and user experience to make the process intuitive and efficient for the user.

Comment: Why are SVMs generally not easily updated? How do online SVMs fix that? What is it about Naive Bayes and nearest neighbors that allows incremental updating? Please [edit] to clarify.